# eclipse-neon bower-install can't run due to error in the file

Tags: npm-install, bower-install, eclipse-neon

I create javascript project and bower.json. After adding dependencies as follow gives me red-cross on project->bower_components->bootstrap->grunt->change-version.js file and query->src file:

```
 "dependencies":{
  "bootstrap":"~3.3.7"
```

}

This is first problem:

```
 Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Expected name at 2:1    .eslintrc.json  /gruntTest/bower_components/jquery/src  line 2  JSON Problem
```

Second problem:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unexpected token ILLEGAL    change-version.js   /gruntTest/bower_components/bootstrap/grunt line 1  JavaScript Problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that eclipse neon doesn't need to download Nodeclipse & Enide and try to practice from scratch thats the reason error happened.

Nodeclipse & Enide must installed before practicing nodejs in eclipse.
I followed this link and worked great.
http://www.nodeclipse.org